# Head bolts over torque now what?

Tags: head-gasket, cylinder-head, torque-specification

Doing a head gasket job on a Civic D16Y7 bought a brand new torque wrench (from the hft) turns out the torque wrench was/is faulty (won't even click clamped to a vice) over torqued a couple head bolts before I realized (The bolts seemed to get loose but still seem to be torqued to spec which I verified with a good torque wrench)  what do I do now? Do I order a new head gasket and bolts? I'm worried that if I take the bolts out now the aluminum threads will come out of the block.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking,

> "I messed up but it is OK?"

My answer is NO, this is not OK!  You need to disassemble the engine and assess the damage.  If the threads come out of the block, better now than after you've re-installed the engine in the vehicle.

As a minimum your head bolts need to be replaced.  It's possible you damaged the cylinder head and even the engine block.  If so, those will need to be repaired if possible or replaced.

Sorry, there are no quick and easy fixes here.  Of course you could also just keep going and take your chances but if this were MY project, I'd want to know it was done properly.